# extract ID from JSON filtering by value

Tags: jsonpath

I have the following JSON file

```
{
    "businessEventData": [
        {
            "businessEvent": {
                "header": {
                    "moduleName": "Reservation",
                    "primaryKey": "45901",
                    "createdDateTime": "2021-09-26 11:58:03.0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "businessEvent": {
                "header": {
                    "moduleName": "Reservation",
                    "primaryKey": "45901",
                    "createdDateTime": "2021-09-26 11:58:15.0"
                }
                
            }
            
        },
         {
            "businessEvent": {
                "header": {
                    "moduleName": "Profile",
                    "primaryKey": "45902",
                    "createdDateTime": "2021-09-25 11:58:03.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to extract the `primaryKey` in the json object where the moduleName is equal to "Reservation". My desired output would be:

```
[
  "45901",
  "45901"
]
```

If I run the followig jsonPath  `$..header[?@.moduleName == "Reservation"].primaryKey` I don't get any output.

As well, is there a way to get a unique list with jsonPath? Instead of:

```
[
  "45901",
  "45901"
]
```

to get

```
 [
   "45901"
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
$.businessEventData[?(@.businessEvent.header.moduleName=='Reservation')]..header.primaryKey
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to extract the primaryKey in the json object where the moduleName is equal to "Reservation".

Not jsonpath but python 1 liner

```
data = {
    "businessEventData": [
        {
            "businessEvent": {
                "header": {
                    "moduleName": "Reservation",
                    "primaryKey": "45901",
                    "createdDateTime": "2021-09-26 11:58:03.0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "businessEvent": {
                "header": {
                    "moduleName": "Reservation",
                    "primaryKey": "45901",
                    "createdDateTime": "2021-09-26 11:58:15.0"
                }

            }

        },
        {
            "businessEvent": {
                "header": {
                    "moduleName": "Profile",
                    "primaryKey": "45902",
                    "createdDateTime": "2021-09-25 11:58:03.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

values = [x['businessEvent']['header']['primaryKey'] for x in data['businessEventData'] if
          x['businessEvent']['header']['moduleName'] == 'Reservation']

print(values)
```

output

```
['45901', '45901']
```